# How to convert all float element to integer element of a vector

Tags: matlab

I have a problem that need your help. I have a vector such as

```
P=[ -0.0610    0.1219    0.2439   -0.1829 ]
```

It is similar the

```
P =[-242/3969 484/3969 968/3969 -242/1323]
```

Now I want to convert all coefficient of P to integer, that mean I must find a leading coefficient c of P such that f=P/c has all its elements are integer
We can find c=-3969/242 and f is

```
   f=P/c=[1 -2 -4 3]
```

However, I don't know how to find the coefficient c . Does matlab has some function to find it? Thank you so much

Comment: Once you've converted to floating-point, rounding has occurred and it is too late to do this exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approximate rational fractions with the function `rat`:

```
[N,D] = rat(P)
```

Here `P=N/D`

Since the practical example is a little screwy for the reasons reported by @BenVoigt, let's assume you know that `N=[-242 484 968 -242]` and `D=[3969 3969 3969 1323]`. If you have the Symbolic Math toolbox you can solve it right away  with the `lcm` function. If you don't you can do something like:

```
LCMD=1;
for k=1:numel(D)
    LCM=lcm(LCM, D(k));
end 

GCDN=gcd(abs(N(1)), abs(N(2)));
for k=1:numel(N)-2
   GCDN=gcd(GCDN, abs(N(k+2)));
end
```

And `c` will be `LCMD/GCDN`.

Comment: Thank Cape Code: I used rat function such as your suggestion. However, How to find c value. My goal is convert float vector P to f

Comment: @user8430 oh I see, you want the least common multiple?

Comment: Right. It is least common multiple. But it is only support in MUPAD. I am looking for function in matlab. Thanks